# Recursive Merge Sort Java Program

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, merge

I've been working on a merge sort recursive code and I've hit a speed bump. I've gone through the internet and my algorithm itself on paper MANY times and I just can't seem to figure out the problem.

```
    public static int[] mergesort(int[] data, int low, int high)
    {
        int middle = (high+low)/2;
        if (middle==low)
        {
            int[] data2 = new int [1];
            data2[0]=data[middle];
            return data2;
        }
        else
        {
            int[] firstHalfSorted = mergesort(data, low, middle);
            int[] secondHalfSorted = mergesort(data, middle+1, high);
            return (merge(firstHalfSorted, secondHalfSorted));
        }
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] firstHalfSorted, int[] secondHalfSorted)
    {
        int[] SortedArray = new int[firstHalfSorted.length+secondHalfSorted.length];
        int m = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (m<firstHalfSorted.length && n<secondHalfSorted.length)
        {
            if (firstHalfSorted[m]>secondHalfSorted[n])
            {
                SortedArray[count]=secondHalfSorted[n];
                count++;
                n++;
            }
            else if (firstHalfSorted[m]<secondHalfSorted[n])
            {
                SortedArray[count]=firstHalfSorted[m];
                count++;
                m++;
            }
        }
        if (m!=firstHalfSorted.length)
        {
            while(m<firstHalfSorted.length){
                SortedArray[count]=firstHalfSorted[m];
                count++;
                m++;
            }
        }
        if (n!=secondHalfSorted.length)
        {
            while(n<secondHalfSorted.length){
                SortedArray[count]=secondHalfSorted[n];
                count++;
                n++;
            }
        }
        return SortedArray;
    }
```

There's the code. The problem is from a text input file with numbers, 3,9,7,2,10,5,1,8 in that order, the code only sorts every other number, being 3,7 and 10,1, then 3,7,1,10.

By all my thinking it should sort 3,9 then 7,2 and so on then, 3,9,7,2 and 10,5,1,8 and so on and so on, but it does not! Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: your mergesort method looks different / wrong

Comment: Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: Please, post only relevant code. It seems to me that you have no problems with file I/O. Then just initialize sample array in code and remove irrelevant file read/write code from code sample. Irrelevant code just shows that you're not willing to put any effort in solving your problem.

Comment: Edited out the code that was irrelevant to the problem. Sorry! I believe it's just a problem with my merge or mergesort methods

Comment: `main` method was OK to me. I just was expecting plain initialization and run there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problematic code is:

```
if (middle==low)
{
    int[] data2 = new int [1];
    data2[0]=data[middle];
    return data2;
}
```

This code will return one element array when `high-low<=1`. So, for `low = 0, high=1` method will return zeroth element when it expected to return sorted two-element array. You can change it to:

```
if(low==high) //one element passed
//same here
```

Comment: There we go! LOVELY! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarcHosang Happy to hear that. If you find this answer helpful, consider accepting it (there is a checkbox to the left of answer). Check out the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the following two things here:

1) Change `if (middle==low)` to `if (high==low)` as pointed in the previous post.

2) Change `else if (firstHalfSorted[m] **<** secondHalfSorted[n])` to `else if (firstHalfSorted[m] **<=** secondHalfSorted[n])` or simply `else`.

The second point is important because currently your code does not support repeated numbers. In other words, your `if-else` were not exhaustive in the sense that they don't consider the case when both `firstHalfSorted[m]` and `secondHalfSorted[n]` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

For merge-sort, you need only to divide your data into two parts, recurse on those two parts, and then merge. Instead of trying to divide your data by finding the middle or whatever it is you are trying to do, instead just separate the whole list into two halves.

For example:

```
private int[] mergesort(int[] data) {
    int[] half1 = new int[data.length / 2];
    int[] half2 = new int[(data.length % 2 == 0)? data.length / 2 : data.length / 2 + 1];
    for (int i = 0; 2 * i < data.length; i++) {
        half2[i] = data[2 * i];
        if (2 * i + 1 < data.length) half1[i] = data[2 * i + 1];
    }
    int[] firstHalfSorted = mergesort(half1);
    int[] secondHalfSorted = mergesort(half2);
    return merge(firstHalfSorted, secondHalfSorted);
}
```

If you want to keep your current method (which actually looks like it should work), you just need to fix the integer-division bug by changing `if (middle == low)` to `if (high == low)`.

Comment: Well I was hoping that finding the middle, then splitting it there, then repeating on each instance of merge-sort until they're was one pair left, then sorting each would have worked out.

Comment: I guess I see where you're going with that. Maybe your problem then is the integer division. If low and high are 1 apart, the first case will fire, which loses the other element you want to consider. Instead, I would change your check to be: `if (data.length == 1)`

Comment: Well yeah, the first return is the 3 as expected, but then I expect middle+1 to become low, then low+high would be the other value.

For example, 2+3/2 = 2
then 2+1+3/2 = 3

Comment: That won't work with this algorithm unfortunately. Not to sound ungrateful! I'm really thankful for the help

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but here's why only half the numbers are sorted:

Consider the case where low == 0 and high == 1. Thus we are considering elements 0 and 1. low + 1 / 2 = 0, so middle == 0. middle == low, so we return an array containing only the 0th element. Element 1 is thus completely forgotten.

Comment: Oh sorry I see why my previous suggestion won't work. Use `if (high == low)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple merge sort code with recursion.

```
public class solution {

 public static void merge(int[] input, int s, int e){

    int m = (s + e) / 2;

    int temp[] = new int[e - s + 1];

    int s1 = s;
    int s2 = m + 1;

    int i = s1;
    int j = s2;
    int p = 0;
    while(i <= m  && j <= e){
        if(input[i] > input[j]){
            temp[p] = input[j];
            j++;
            p++;
        }else{
            temp[p] = input[i];
            i++;
            p++;
        }
    }//end of while loop

    while(i <= m){
            temp[p] = input[i];
            p++;
            i++;
    }
    while(j <= e){
            temp[p] = input[j];
            p++;
            j++;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++){
        input[s + k] = temp[k];
    }
}

public static void callsort(int[] input, int s, int e){

    if(s >= e){
        return ;
    }

    int m = (s + e) / 2;

    callsort(input, s, m);
    callsort(input, m + 1, e);
    merge(input, s, e);

}

public static void mergeSort(int[] input){
    callsort(input , 0 , input.length - 1); 
}
}
```

Input: 5 6 3 2 1 4
output: 1 2 3 4 5 6